# populate pandas DataFrame from JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I want to iterate through a JSON file and populate a pandas DataFrame via iterating through specific key values of the JSON data.

```
import pandas as pd
json_data = [
{
    "name" : "Brad Green",
    "age" : "35",
    "address" : {
        "street" : "Nicol St. 16",
        "city" : "Manhatan"
    },
    "children" : ["Nati", "Madi"]
},

{
    "name" : "Sara Brown",
    "age" : "30",
    "address" : {
        "street" : "Adam St. 66",
        "city" : "New York"
    },
    "children" : "none" 
}
]
```

I don't want to simply add the data from `json_data` to the df like the code below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json_data, columns=['name', 'address', 'age'])
```

I wrote a for loop to iterate through the `json_data` and add the data to `df_new`:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','age','street','city'])

for i in range(len(json_data)):
    df_new = df_new.append({"name": json_data[i]})
...
```

I know that this for loop obviously can't get the `'name','age','street','city` values from `json_data` but I couldn't manage to find a solution by looking at different posts here. Plus, I want to get the data from `address` values separately from this nested key value. I would appreciate it if anyone can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating through the json file is maybe not the best way to do this IMO. I'd look into [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) if I were you:

```
>>> df = pd.json_normalize(json_data)[['name', 'age', 'address.street', 'address.city']] 
>>> df

         name age address.street address.city
0  Brad Green  35   Nicol St. 16     Manhatan
1  Sara Brown  30    Adam St. 66     New York
```

You can rename the columns as you see fit after this, e.g.

```
df.columns = ["name", "age", "street", "city"]
```

**Fixing your code**

I wouldn't recommend this method, but to address your specific question about iterating through the json: you could get the dataframe using something like:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','age','street','city'])

for kv in json_data2:
    df_new = df_new.append(
        {
            "name": kv.get("name", None),
            "age": kv.get("age", None),
            "street": kv.get("address", {}).get("street", None),
            "city": kv.get("address", {}).get("city", None),
        },
        ignore_index=True
    )
```

Note I'm using `.get()` with a default value of `None` so that this won't fail if you have an inconsistantly structured record in your json (e.g. missing one of the required keys)

Answer (score 0):

Use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to collate the data while iterating, before creating the dataframe, should be more efficient that using [json.normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
from collections import defaultdict

df = defaultdict(list)

for entry in json_data:
     df['name'].append(entry['name'])
     df['age'].append(entry['age'])
     df['street'].append(entry['address']['street'])
     df['city'].append(entry['address']['city'])

df

defaultdict(list,
            {'name': ['Brad Green', 'Sara Brown'],
             'age': ['35', '30'],
             'street': ['Nicol St. 16', 'Adam St. 66'],
             'city': ['Manhatan', 'New York']})
```

Create dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(df)
 
         name age        street      city
0  Brad Green  35  Nicol St. 16  Manhatan
1  Sara Brown  30   Adam St. 66  New York
```

You could also use [jmespath](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/), but I think it is overkill, as the json here is not too nested; still I'll add it here, in case you ever need to traverse nested json data. Summary for using [jmespath](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/), if it is a key, access with a `.`, if it is an array, access with `[]`:

```
import jmespath

df = jmespath.search("""{name:[].name, 
                         age: [].age, 
                         street: [].address.street, 
                         city: [].address.city}
                     """, 
                     json_data)

pd.DataFrame(df)
 
         name age        street      city
0  Brad Green  35  Nicol St. 16  Manhatan
1  Sara Brown  30   Adam St. 66  New York
```